# GAE development server ignores "threadsafe" flag

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

I'm using eclipse with Cloud Tools plugin for my GAE application (Java). I'm trying to make my servlet dispatch multiply requests, so I added the flag `<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>` in appengine-web.xml. But regardless the flag value, development server keeps dispatch requests serial (in single thread).

When I deployed the project to production then in works fine there. Also it used to work with Google plugin for Eclipse. So I supposed the problem is in Cloud Tools plugin or how I use it.

ps: the flag value keeps to be ignored even if it not valid boolean.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin does not support multithreading in local run/debug: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/498#issuecomment-250295446